# Why do I get this warning?

Tags: c, c99, keil

I'm trying to write this program:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "ILI9325.h"


/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/





/*******************************************************************************
* Function Name  : main
* Description    : Main Program
* Input          : None
* Output         : None
* Return         : None
* Attention      : None
*******************************************************************************/


int main(void)
{
    uint8_t b,c;

    Lcd_Configuration();
    Lcd_Initialize();
    Lcd_Clear(0xffff);
    Lcd_Clear(0x0000);
    Lcd_Clear(0xff00);
    for ( b = 0 ; b < 200 ; b++ )
    {
        for ( c = 0 ; c < 200 ; c++ )
        {
            DrawPixel( b , c , 0xffff );
        }       
    }

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1)
    {

  }
}
```

But I get this warning(yellow title):

> implicit declaration of function "DrawPixel"

as in the below snapshot

[image: figure1]

I have seen a lot question about this warning and I think everythings are ok but still I get this warning.

`ILI9325.h` file :

```
#ifndef __ILI9325_H 
#define __ILI9325_H 

// ILI9320 or ILI9325 
#define  ILI9325  


#define ID_AM  110 
extern u16 q; 

//#define Delay //Display Delay//Immediately 

#define Set_Cs  GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_8); 
#define Clr_Cs  GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_8); 

#define Set_Rs  GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_9); 
#define Clr_Rs  GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_9); 

#define Set_nWr GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_10); 
#define Clr_nWr GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_10); 

#define Set_nRd GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_11); 
#define Clr_nRd GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_11); 

#define Set_Rst GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_12); 
#define Clr_Rst GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_12); 

#define Lcd_Light_ON   GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_13); 
#define Lcd_Light_OFF  GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_13); 

typedef union 
{ 
  u16 U16; 
  u8 U8[2]; 
}ColorTypeDef; 


void Lcd_Configuration(void); 
void DataToWrite(u16 data); 
void LCD_WR_REG(u16 Index,u16 CongfigTemp);
void Lcd_Initialize(void); 
void Lcd_WR_Start(void); 
void Lcd_SetCursor(u8 x,u16 y); 
void Lcd_Clear(u16 Color); 
void Lcd_ClearCharBox(u8 x,u16 y,u16 Color); 
void Lcd_SetBox(u8 xStart,u16 yStart,u8 xLong,u16 yLong,u16 x_offset,u16 y_offset); 
void Lcd_ColorBox(u8 x,u16 y,u8 xLong,u16 yLong,u16 Color); 

void Delay_nms(int n); 
//u16 Read9325(void); 


#define logo 0x51000 
#define key24048 0x4a000 
#define key8048 0x48000 
#define key2480 0x77000 
#define key2448 0x78000 
#define BatteryHight 0x79000 
#define BatteryMiddle 0x7a000 
#define BatteryLow 0x7b000 
#define BatteryTooLow 0x7c000 
#define key24032 0x80000  
#define PowOffkey24048 0x84000 

#define ASCII_Offset 0x47000 
#define Chinese_Offset 0x1000 

#endif
```

And `ILI9325.c` file:

```
void Lcd_Configuration(void)   
{    
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;   

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA|RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB|RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);     

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_11|GPIO_Pin_12|GPIO_Pin_13|GPIO_Pin_14|GPIO_Pin_15;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0|GPIO_Pin_1|GPIO_Pin_2|GPIO_Pin_3|GPIO_Pin_4|GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_6|GPIO_Pin_7;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_11|GPIO_Pin_12;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =GPIO_Pin_13;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);   
} 



void DataToWrite(u16 data)    
{   
    u16 temp;   
    temp = GPIO_ReadOutputData(GPIOB);   
    GPIO_Write(GPIOB, (data<<8)|(temp&0x00ff));   
    temp = GPIO_ReadOutputData(GPIOC);   
    GPIO_Write(GPIOC, (data>>8)|(temp&0xff00));   
}

void LCD_WR_REG(u16 Index,u16 CongfigTemp)   
{   
    Clr_Cs;   
    Clr_Rs;   
    Set_nRd;   
    DataToWrite(Index);   
    Clr_nWr;   
    Set_nWr;   
    Set_Rs;          
    DataToWrite(CongfigTemp);          
    Clr_nWr;   
    Set_nWr;   
    Set_Cs;   
}

u16 CheckController(void)   
{   
    u16 tmp=0,tmp1=0,tmp2=0;    
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;   

    DataToWrite(0xffff);
    Set_Rst;   
    Set_nWr;   
    Set_Cs;   
    Set_Rs;   
    Set_nRd;   
    Set_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);   
    Clr_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);   
    Set_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0000,0x0001);  //start oscillation   
    Delay_nms(1);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_11|GPIO_Pin_12|GPIO_Pin_13|GPIO_Pin_14|GPIO_Pin_15;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0|GPIO_Pin_1|GPIO_Pin_2|GPIO_Pin_3|GPIO_Pin_4|GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_6|GPIO_Pin_7;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_8);   

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_9);   

    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_11);   

    tmp1 = GPIO_ReadInputData(GPIOB);   
    tmp2 = GPIO_ReadInputData(GPIOC);   

    tmp = (tmp1>>8) | (tmp2<<8);   

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_11);   

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_8);   


    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_11|GPIO_Pin_12|GPIO_Pin_13|GPIO_Pin_14|GPIO_Pin_15;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0|GPIO_Pin_1|GPIO_Pin_2|GPIO_Pin_3|GPIO_Pin_4|GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_6|GPIO_Pin_7;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    return tmp;   
}



void Lcd_Initialize(void)   
{   
    u16 i;
    Lcd_Light_ON;   
    DataToWrite(0xffff);
    Set_Rst;   
    Set_nWr;   
    Set_Cs;   
    Set_Rs;   
    Set_nRd;   
    Set_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);   
    Clr_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);   
    Set_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);    

/*        
#ifdef ILI9325          
    LCD_WR_REG(0x00e3,0x3008);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x00e7,0x0010);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x00ef,0x1231);  //Set the internal vcore voltage  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0001,0x0100);  //When SS = 0, the shift direction of outputs is from S1 to S720                                  
#endif                          //When SS = 1, the shift direction of outputs is from S720 to S1.  
#ifdef ILI9320  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x00e5,0x8000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0000,0x0001);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0001,0x0100);//S  
    Delay_nms(10);  
#endif          
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0002,0x0700);//Line inversion          
#if   ID_AM==000         
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0000);
#elif ID_AM==001          
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0008);        
#elif ID_AM==010    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0010);          
#elif ID_AM==011  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0018);  
#elif ID_AM==100    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0020);        
#elif ID_AM==101    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0028);        
#elif ID_AM==110    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0030);        
#elif ID_AM==111    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0038);  
#endif        
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0004,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0008,0x0207);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0009,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x000a,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x000c,0x0001);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x000d,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x000f,0x0000);        

    LCD_WR_REG(0x0010,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0011,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0012,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0013,0x0000);  
    Delay_nms(200);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0010,0x17b0);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0011,0x0137);  
    Delay_nms(50);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0012,0x0139);  
    Delay_nms(50);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0013,0x1700);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0029,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x002b,0x0000);  
    Delay_nms(50);        
#if   ID_AM==000           
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x00ef);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x013f);        
#elif ID_AM==001  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x00ef);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x013f);        
#elif ID_AM==010  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x013f);        
#elif ID_AM==011  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x013f);         
#elif ID_AM==100  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x00ef);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);        
#elif ID_AM==101    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x00ef);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);        
#elif ID_AM==110  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);        
#elif ID_AM==111  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);           
#endif         
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0030,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0031,0x0507);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0032,0x0104);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0035,0x0105);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0036,0x0404);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0037,0x0603);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0038,0x0004);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0039,0x0007);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x003c,0x0501);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x003d,0x0404);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,0x0000);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,0x00ef);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,0x0000);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,0x013f);
#ifdef ILI9325          
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0060,0xa700);//G  
#endif  
#ifdef ILI9320          
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0060,0x2700);//G    
#endif      
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0061,0x0001);//Enables the grayscale inversion of the image by setting REV=1.??????????????????????????????  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x006a,0x0000);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0080,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0081,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0082,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0083,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0084,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0085,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0090,0x0010);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0092,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0093,0x0003);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0095,0x0110);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0097,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0098,0x0000);       

    LCD_WR_REG(0x0007,0x0130);  
#ifdef Immediately  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0007,0x0173);        
#endif            
       */
    i = CheckController();   
    q=i;        
    if(i==0x9325||i==0x9328)   
    {   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x00e7,0x0010);         
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0000,0x0001);              //start internal osc   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0001,0x0100);        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0002,0x0700);              //power on sequence                        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,(1<<12)|(1<<5)|(1<<4) );    //65K    
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0004,0x0000);                                      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0008,0x0207);                
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0009,0x0000);            
        LCD_WR_REG(0x000a,0x0000);              //display setting            
        LCD_WR_REG(0x000c,0x0001);              //display setting             
        LCD_WR_REG(0x000d,0x0000);              //0f3c             
        LCD_WR_REG(0x000f,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0010,0x0000);      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0011,0x0007);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0012,0x0000);                                                                    
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0013,0x0000);                    
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0010,0x1590);      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0011,0x0227);   
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0012,0x009c);                    
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0013,0x1900);      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0029,0x0023);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x002b,0x000e);   
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);                                                               
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);                    

        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0030,0x0007);    
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0031,0x0707);      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0032,0x0006);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0035,0x0704);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0036,0x1f04);    
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0037,0x0004);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0038,0x0000);           
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0039,0x0706);        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x003c,0x0701);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x003d,0x000f);   
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,0x0000);           
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,0x00ef);      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,0x0000);        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,0x013f);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0060,0xa700);           
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0061,0x0001);    
        LCD_WR_REG(0x006a,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0080,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0081,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0082,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0083,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0084,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0085,0x0000);   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x0090,0x0010);        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0092,0x0000);     
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0093,0x0003);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0095,0x0110);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0097,0x0000);           
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0098,0x0000);     
         //display on sequence        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0007,0x0133);   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);                                                               
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);   
    }   
    else if(i==0x9320)   
    {   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x00,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x01,0x0100);    //Driver Output Contral.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x02,0x0700);    //LCD Driver Waveform Contral.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x03,0x1030);    //Entry Mode Set.   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x04,0x0000);    //Scalling Contral.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x08,0x0202);    //Display Contral 2.(0x0207)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x09,0x0000);    //Display Contral 3.(0x0000)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0a,0x0000);    //Frame Cycle Contal.(0x0000)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0c,(1<<0));  //Extern Display Interface Contral 1.(0x0000)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0d,0x0000);    //Frame Maker Position.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0f,0x0000);    //Extern Display Interface Contral 2.   

        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x07,0x0101);    //Display Contral.   
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x10,(1<<12)|(0<<8)|(1<<7)|(1<<6)|(0<<4)); //Power Control 1.(0x16b0)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x11,0x0007);                                //Power Control 2.(0x0001)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x12,(1<<8)|(1<<4)|(0<<0));                    //Power Control 3.(0x0138)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x13,0x0b00);                                //Power Control 4.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x29,0x0000);                                //Power Control 7.   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x2b,(1<<14)|(1<<4));   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x50,0);     //Set X Start.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x51,239);   //Set X End.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x52,0);     //Set Y Start.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x53,319);   //Set Y End.   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x60,0x2700);    //Driver Output Control.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x61,0x0001);    //Driver Output Control.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x6a,0x0000);    //Vertical Srcoll Control.   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x80,0x0000);    //Display Position? Partial Display 1.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x81,0x0000);    //RAM Address Start? Partial Display 1.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x82,0x0000);    //RAM Address End-Partial Display 1.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x83,0x0000);    //Displsy Position? Partial Display 2.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x84,0x0000);    //RAM Address Start? Partial Display 2.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x85,0x0000);    //RAM Address End? Partial Display 2.   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x90,(0<<7)|(16<<0));    //Frame Cycle Contral.(0x0013)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x92,0x0000);    //Panel Interface Contral 2.(0x0000)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x93,0x0001);    //Panel Interface Contral 3.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x95,0x0110);    //Frame Cycle Contral.(0x0110)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x97,(0<<8));  //   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x98,0x0000);    //Frame Cycle Contral.   


        LCD_WR_REG(0x07,0x0173);    //(0x0173)   
    }   
}   



void Lcd_WR_Start(void)   
{   
    Clr_Cs;   
    Clr_Rs;   
    Set_nRd;   
    DataToWrite(0x0022);   
    Clr_nWr;   
    Set_nWr;   
    Set_Rs;   
}  



void Lcd_SetCursor(u8 x,u16 y)   
{    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x20,x);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x21,y);       
} 



void Lcd_Clear(u16 Color)   
{   
    u32 temp;   

    Lcd_SetCursor(0x00, 0x0000);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,0x00);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,239);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,0x00); 
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,319);     
    Lcd_WR_Start();   
    Set_Rs;   

    for (temp = 0; temp < 76800; temp++)   
    {   
        DataToWrite(Color);   
        Clr_nWr;   
        Set_nWr;   
    }   

    Set_Cs;   
}   



void Lcd_SetBox(u8 xStart,u16 yStart,u8 xLong,u16 yLong,u16 x_offset,u16 y_offset)   
{   

#if ID_AM==000       
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+xLong-1+x_offset,yStart+yLong-1+y_offset);   

#elif ID_AM==001   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+xLong-1+x_offset,yStart+yLong-1+y_offset);   

#elif ID_AM==010   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+x_offset,yStart+yLong-1+y_offset);   

#elif ID_AM==011    
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+x_offset,yStart+yLong-1+y_offset);   

#elif ID_AM==100   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+xLong-1+x_offset,yStart+y_offset);        

#elif ID_AM==101   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+xLong-1+x_offset,yStart+y_offset);        

#elif ID_AM==110   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+x_offset,yStart+y_offset);    

#elif ID_AM==111   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+x_offset,yStart+y_offset);     

#endif   

    LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,xStart+x_offset); 
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,xStart+xLong-1+x_offset);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,yStart+y_offset); 
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,yStart+yLong-1+y_offset);  
}   


void Lcd_ColorBox(u8 xStart,u16 yStart,u8 xLong,u16 yLong,u16 Color)   
{   
    u32 temp;   

    Lcd_SetBox(xStart,yStart,xLong,yLong,0,0);   
    Lcd_WR_Start();   
    Set_Rs;   

    for (temp=0; temp<xLong*yLong; temp++)   
    {   
        DataToWrite(Color);   
        Clr_nWr;   
        Set_nWr;   
    }   

    Set_Cs;   
}   


void Lcd_ClearCharBox(u8 x,u16 y,u16 Color)   
{   
    u32 temp;   

    Lcd_SetBox(x*8,y*16,8,16,0,0);    
    Lcd_WR_Start();   
    Set_Rs;   

    for (temp=0; temp < 128; temp++)   
    {   
        DataToWrite(Color);    
        Clr_nWr;   
        //Delay_nus(22);   
        Set_nWr;    
    }   

    Set_Cs;   
}   




void Delay_nms(int n)   
{   

  u32 f=n,k;   
  for (; f!=0; f--)   
  {   
    for(k=0xFFF; k!=0; k--);   
  }   

}   
void DrawPixel(u16 x, u16 y, int Color)   
{   
    Lcd_SetCursor(x,y);   
    Lcd_WR_Start();    
    Set_Rs;   
    DataToWrite(Color);   
    Clr_nWr;   
    Set_nWr;                                 
    Set_Cs;   
}   
void DispPic240_320(const unsigned char *str)   
{   

    u32 temp;   
    ColorTypeDef color;   
    Lcd_SetCursor(0x00, 0x0000);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,0x00);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,239);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,0);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,319);   
    Lcd_WR_Start();   
    Set_Rs;   

    for (temp = 0; temp < 240*320; temp++)   
    {     
        color.U8[1] =*(unsigned short *)(&str[ 2 * temp]);   
        color.U8[0]=*(unsigned short *)(&str[ 2 * temp+1]);   
        //DataToWrite(i);   

        DataToWrite(color.U16);   
        Clr_nWr;   
        Set_nWr;   
    }   

//==============================     
}   
void test_color(void){   
  u8  R_data,G_data,B_data,i,j;   

    Lcd_SetCursor(0x00, 0x0000);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,0x00);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,239);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,0);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,319); 
    Lcd_WR_Start();   
    Set_Rs;   
    R_data=0;G_data=0;B_data=0;        
    for(j=0;j<50;j++)
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {R_data=i/8;DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;Set_nWr;}   
    }   
    R_data=0x1f;G_data=0x3f;B_data=0x1f;   
    for(j=0;j<50;j++)   
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {   
            G_data=0x3f-(i/4);   
            B_data=0x1f-(i/8);   
            DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;   
            Set_nWr;   
            }   
    }   
//----------------------------------   
    R_data=0;G_data=0;B_data=0;   
    for(j=0;j<50;j++)
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {G_data=i/4;   
            DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;   
            Set_nWr;}   
    }   

    R_data=0x1f;G_data=0x3f;B_data=0x1f;   
    for(j=0;j<50;j++)   
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {   
            R_data=0x1f-(i/8);   
            B_data=0x1f-(i/8);   
            DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;   
            Set_nWr;   
        }   
    }   
//----------------------------------   

    R_data=0;G_data=0;B_data=0;   
    for(j=0;j<60;j++)  
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {B_data=i/8;DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;   
            Set_nWr;}   
    }    

    B_data=0;    
    R_data=0x1f;G_data=0x3f;B_data=0x1f;   

    for(j=0;j<60;j++)   
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {   
            G_data=0x3f-(i/4);   
            R_data=0x1f-(i/8);   
            DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;   
            Set_nWr;   
        }   
    }        
    Set_Cs;   
}
```

And at end, I have a question which I'm not sure it's relevant to the thread but if you look at the picture, you will know there is an error. the error is this:

```
linking...
.
\Obj\Project.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol q (referred from ili9325.o).

Not enough information to list image symbols.

Finished: 1 information, 0 warning and 1 error messages.

".\Obj\Project.axf" - 1 Error(s), 1 Warning(s).

Target not created
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The `DrawPixel` function is defined in `ILI9325.c` but not declared in `ILI9325.h`.

Comment: Dude... A *minimal* code snipet that reproduces the problem is what is needed. Not the entire source code. Nobody is going to analyze all of this in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a prototype for `DrawPixel` to `ILI9325.h`:

```
void DrawPixel(u16 x, u16 y, int Color);
```

The error during linking is due to this declaration in the header file:

```
extern u16 q;
```

This requires a corresponding global variable declaration in one of the `.c` files, but there isn't one.  If you do need this variable, you need to define it somewhere. If not, remove the extraneous declaration. I hope the answer is that you don't need it -- single-letter external variables are not a good idea.

Comment: The header file has `extern u16 q;`, but that external variable is never defined anywhere. The only `q` variable in `ILI9325.c` is a local variable in the `Lcd_Initialize` function.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. the problem completely solved. I'm going to choose your response as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1.** To resolve the *implicit declaration*:

Please add the function prototype in your header file `ILI9325.h` so that the function forward declaration is present in `ILI9325.c` when you `#include "ILI9325.h"`.

`void DrawPixel(u16 x, u16 y, int Color);`

**Point 2:** To resolve the *undefined symbol*:

You have added `extern u16 q;` in the header file, you've used `q` in the `Lcd_Initialize()` function, but you've not defined a *global* `q` anywhere in your code.

Remember, `extern u16 q` is the ***declaration***, not the ***definition***. That's why, you compiler complains about `Undefined symbol q` at linking time.